# How to process an object array of a class in display tag library

Tags: java, displaytag

I am using the Display Tag Library, Here my problem is I need to process and print an object array using display tag library.
I will explain my problem, I have two classes named

```
    public class StudentAddress {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

And second class

```
import java.util.List;

public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String city;
    private List<String> interests;
    private StudentAddress[] address;

    public StudentAddress[] getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(StudentAddress[] address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public List<String> getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }
    public void setInterests(List<String> interests) {
        this.interests = interests;
    }

}
```

so Here  using display tag I need to display array of StudentAddress in the jsp page, I tried by googling but not found any sample to process the object array sp need help to process this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the Solution we can use the display tag in  this manner

```
<display:table name="studentobj">
<display:column property="id" title="StudentId"/>
<display:column property="firstname" title="FirstName"/>
<display:column title="Student Address">
<%-- it will displays all the address objects properties if we need some we may user column tags inside table tag--%>
    <display:table name="studentobj.address"> 
    </display:table>
</display:column>
</display:table>
```